# ReactJS- Only latest line of text is appearing in web page

Tags: reactjs

I have this class function

```
class Fact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

           <img src="Logo.png"/>,
           <center><p>FACT</p></center>,
           <h1>Hello</h1>

        )
    }
}

export default Fact;
```

When running my localhost server, only "Hello" appears on the webpage. The logo doesn't appear, or the text message "FACT". Only "Hello" appears...How do I fix this?

Im trying to fit in 3 paragraphs as text to appear on my website, along with the logo. What's the best practice for this, rather then spam ?

Comment: Your h1 tag is unclosed too...

Comment: Thanks! I added that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the render output within a "root element", such as a `<div>` element to ensure that reactjs renders all the contents of the `Fact` component as you are expecting.

See the comments and code below, showing how to correct the error:

```
class Fact extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div> {/* Add <div> opening tag here */} 
               <img src="Logo.png"/>,
               <center><p>FACT</p></center>,
               <h1>Hello</h1>
          </div> {/* Add </div> closing tag here */}
        )
    }
}
```

Note also that `</h1>` is missing the `>` in your question. This has been corrected in my answer

Comment: @R.SMohanAravind you're welcome - glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

In React, if you're rendering multiple nodes (e.g. img, center, h1), you need to nest them under one parent node, e.g. `<div>`. That is, you can only return **one** top level node from your render function.

So:

```
class Fact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <img src="Logo.png" /> ,
        <center>
          <p>FACT</p>
        </center>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that `React.Fragment` could also be something like a `div`.